# Dirac delta function representations in physics

Tags: differentiation, fourier-transform, integration, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

The most common representation of the Dirac delta function in physics is
$$\delta(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \,e^{ikx}.$$

My question is in which sense is it a faithful representation and what operations are allowed with this? For example, when I try to get the famous $\partial_x\delta(x)=-\frac{\delta(x)}{x}$ from here, I arrive at

$$\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \; (ik)\,e^{ikx}.$$

I don't know what exactly is legal to do with this but if I naively perform integration by parts, I arrive at the correct result except that there is a oscillating boundary term that has to vanish for some reason.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \; (ik)\,e^{ikx}\overset{?}{=}\frac{1}{2\pi x}. k e^{ikx}\bigl\vert_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\frac{\delta(x)}{x}.$$
Can someone shed some light on what are the allowed operations here?

Comment: You can write the Delta function as a limiting case of many other functions. For example, it is the limiting case of the Lorentzian, Gaussian, etc. It can also be represented as the first derivative of the Heaviside step function. However, you should know that the delta function in its true sense is a distribution, and not a function in the pure sense. For example, it is the derivative of the step function, which as you know itself is not considered a proper function - it is called a generalized function.

Comment: I know all of that but not sure how that answers the question at hand.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I thought about that but most mathematicians would rather not deal with the delta function at all this way. Since it is so heavily used is standard QM, I thought there would some hand-wavy physicist justification.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but to prove the identity you are interested in you can start from $x \delta(x)=0$ and then differentiate with respect to $x$. I think this relationship can be taken to define $\delta(x)$, although I may have got that wrong. I use Dirac delta regularly in different applications and I rarely find I have to use an integral or limit representation for it

Comment: Hi Joe! Yes I am aware of that way of solving the problem. The delta function is sometimes defined as $\delta(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \delta(x) f(x) = f(0) $ for any test function $f(x)$. Thus, I can put f(x)=x to get to the equality you are talking about. However, currently I am interested in what sense is the delta function equal to the integral I referred to above. If it is really equal (in some sense), why does it not produce consistent results?

Comment: Have you tried to apply these definitions / relations to test functions?

Comment: Hint for a hand-waving argument: Show that $ \displaystyle x\,\delta^\prime(x) = \partial_\alpha \delta(\alpha x) \,\Big\vert_{\alpha=1}$ with your definition and then evaluate the RHS by using another well-known property of the delta distribution.